# Installed Tomcat 7 but cannot run apps

Tags: permissions, tomcat, tomcat7

Installed Tomcat7 via repository via `Synaptic package manager`

[image]

& pasted my app(Beerv1) folder to `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/` & also to `/usr/share/tomcat7-root/`

Still gets

> HTTP Status 404 - /Beerv1/form.html

Using:

```
CLASSPATH: /usr/share/tomcat7//bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7//bin/tomcat-juli.jar touch: cannot touch ‘/usr/share/tomcat7//logs/catalina.out’: Permission denied ./catalina.sh: 387: ./catalina.sh: cannot create /usr/share/tomcat7//logs/catalina.out: Permission denied
```

This error shows after I uninstalled Tomcat7 & downloaded package manually from apache-tomcat website, extracted it to (`/usr/share`) & added `CATALINA_HOME=<path>` & `JAVA_HOME=<path>`.

My webapps weren't working on repository package. I pasted my webapps in both folder `/usr/share/tomcat7-root` & `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps`. In Windows just pasting webapps worked but in Ubuntu doesn't. Does it require any extra configuration?

I read somewhere that myapp.xml file should be made in /etc/tomcat7/conf/catalina folder & writing  etc configurations. But that also didn't worked.

Comment: resource not found error...but my app works fine on Windows

Comment: Any error in `catalina.out` or in `locahosthost.<date>.log`?

Comment: how do I ensure this?

Comment: Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7//bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7//bin/tomcat-juli.jar
touch: cannot touch ‘/usr/share/tomcat7//logs/catalina.out’: Permission denied
./catalina.sh: 387: ./catalina.sh: cannot create /usr/share/tomcat7//logs/catalina.out: Permission denied

Comment: This error shows after I uninstalled tomcat7 & downloaded package manually from apache-tomcat website,extracted it to (/usr/share)& added CATALINA_HOME=<path> & JAVA_HOME=<path> @DavidLevesque

Comment: May I ask, what's wrong with the standard repository package?

Comment: external webapps werent working! :\

Comment: Can you elaborate? It was probably just a configuration issue. Personally I would stick with the repository package unless I have very good reasons to do otherwise. It has better integration with the OS.

Comment: my webapps werent working on repository package. I pasted my webapps in both folder /usr/share/tomcat7-root & /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps. In Windows just pasting webapps worked but in ubuntu doesnt. Does it require any extra configuration?

Comment: I read somewhere that myapp.xml file should be made in /etc/tomcat7/conf/catalina folder & writing <contextpath> etc configurations. But that also didnt worked.

Comment: If you understood anything please extend ur answer! :)

Comment: You should just paste your webapp under `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps` (not in two places). Then make sure it has the proper permissions for the user running Tomcat. If it doesn't work, look for errors in the Tomcat logs and post them in your question body.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "Permission denied" error for the logs directory most likely means that the OS user running the Tomcat process does not have write permission on that directory.

Assuming you are running Tomcat with user "tomcat7", try setting the ownership and filesystem permissions of the logs directory, e.g.:

```
sudo chown -R tomcat7:tomcat7 /usr/share/tomcat7/logs
sudo chmod -R u+rw /usr/share/tomcat7/logs
```

If you are running Tomcat with a different OS user, replace `tomcat7:tomcat7` by the username and primary group of that user, respectively.

Comment: Thnx! it worked! :)